# Pusher Laravel-echo error 401 Unauthorized

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, pusher, laravel-echo

I'm having an 401 Unauthorized error, Please help me !

Config/App.php

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

BroadcastServiceProvider.php

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['jwt.auth']]);

require base_path('routes/channels.php');
```

Bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.Pusher.logToConsole = true;
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '6f45c006cfba3fbc72c2',
    cluster: 'ap1',
    encrypted: true,
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')
        },
    },
});
```

Channel.php

```
Broadcast::channel('OnChat', function ($user) {
  if(JWTAuth::check()){
    return $user;
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you please check request parameters which is done for the authentication? is there jwt token passed or not?